# SQL window function over partition by syntax error

Tags: sql

I have a test table with two columns brand and store

| brand | store |
| --- | --- |
| A | a |
| A | b |
| B | a |

I'm trying to use the window function to get the output like this

| brand | store | num_stores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 2 |
| A | b | 2 |
| B | a | 1 |

Here's what I've been trying on both presto sql and sqlite but keep getting "(" syntax error.

```
select brand, store, 
count(store) OVER (PARTITION BY brand) as num_stores
from table
```

Struggling to find why I got this error and how to fix. Appreciate your help :))

Comment: Your given query is alright for mysql https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b8aa1ad2b14a034cbbb7b1813bb6c23

Comment: Tag only the database that you use

Comment: Which database use for it?

Comment: its because mysql version u use , window function doesn't support below 8.0

Answer (score 3):

It could be that your particular database does not support analytic functions.  In that case, you could, as a workaround, try the following:

```sql
SELECT t1.brand, t1.store, t2.cnt AS num_stores
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT brand, COUNT(store) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY brand
) t2
    ON t2.brand = t1.brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below query:

> select brand, store,  count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY brand, store) as
> num_stores from table;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing () brackets for alias covering. You can check my query in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/TLjju16jU5tcVehnSKFdw/1)

```
SELECT 
      Brand, 
      Store, 
      (COUNT(Store) OVER (PARTITION BY Brand)) as Num_Stores
FROM your_table
```